# How to send/receive POST requests via xbee 3g modem, controlled with arduino via serial port

Tags: http, post, arduino, 3g, xbee

I am having trouble performing a successful POST using an Arduino Mega2560 to send via xbee 3g modem (XBC-M5-UT-001).

Using the XCTU software from digi, through the serial terminal, I have been able to:
-Configure the modem using AT commands
-Send/Receive SMS messages
-Send/Receive POST request

Furthermore, controlling the modem via the Arduino, I am able to:
-Configure the modem using AT commands
-Send/Receive SMS messages

But when I attempt to perform the same POST request successfully completed through the terminal, I get no response. I'm not sure if my POST is not getting through, or if the issue lies with the response.

The code below shows how I have been trying to send/receive this request:

```
Serial1.println("POST /loginAjax/ HTTP/1.1");
Serial1.println("Host: dev-aquhivedata.herokuapp.com");
Serial1.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Serial1.println("Content-Length: 28");
Serial1.println("");
Serial1.println("username=E***&pwd=A*********");
Serial1.println("");
Serial1.flush();

while(Serial1.available()) {
  char c = Serial1.read();
  Serial.print(c);
}
```

No Output...

Comment: Can you get a dump of exactly what you're sending on the serial port?  Does `println()` use a CR/LF sequence for line endings, or just LF?  Because you need CR/LF for communication with a web server.

Comment: What protocol are you trying to use? Looks like HTTP but if so, you don't seem to be using the correct procedure according to the [manual](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90002253/Tasks/t_get_http.htm?tocpath=XBee%20connection%20examples%7C_____5)... When you say it works on the terminal, what do you mean exactly? You just write those same commands and you see responses? For HTTP you need and extra CRLF to correctly terminate a request, you don't seem to be doing that either...

Comment: As far as I know, the println() function terminates with CR/LF. I have also tried sending the request as a byte stream, which also does not work: 

char postArray[167]= {50, 4F, 53, 54, 20, 2F, 6C, ... 3D, 45, 2A, 2A, 2A, 26, 70, 77, 64, 3D, 41, 2A, 2A, 2A, 2A, 2A, 2A, 2A, 2A, 2A, 0D, 0A, 0D, 0A}

Comment: Have you looked at the link I posted above? I think you're mixing two protocols.

Comment: Yes, I had seen this previously. I have had no problem with HTTP through the XCTU terminal. Which two protocols do you think I'm mixing?

Answer (score 1):

Change your text delimiter, when you set up the digi modem they have you set your text delimiter to carriage return, or 0. The problem with this is there is a carriage return in each line of an HTTP packet, so if you dont change that, it will try and send each line as a packet ex. [Serial1.println("POST /loginAjax/ HTTP/1.1");] instead of the entire HTTP packet. I went with 24 which is the ascii char for "$".